# Change function on second click

Tags: jquery, click

I have some Divs with class "c01, c02, c03".
When I click on wrap, c01 show first, c02 show next and then c03 show last. But when I click on wrap again, I want to hide c3 first, c2 next and c1 hide last.

Thanks in advance.

```
var wrap = $('#wrap'),
    c01 = $('#c01'),
    c02 = $('#c02'),
    c03 = $('#c03');

wrap.click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        c01.toggleClass('c01');
    }, 0);
    setTimeout(function () {
        c02.toggleClass('c02');
    }, 200);
    setTimeout(function () {
        c03.toggleClass('c03');
    }, 400);
});
```

You can see in http://jsfiddle.net/tZyMY/

Comment: is c01, c02,c03 are classes or Id's ??

Comment: c01, c02, c03 is classes. I'm using same name with Ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this one is closer to your requirements :

```
var children = $('#wrap div'),
    dir = -1,
    idx = -1, 
    tid;
$('#wrap').click(function () {
    tid && clearTimeout(tid);
    dir = -dir;
    idx += dir;
    (function fn() {
        children.eq(idx).toggle(dir > 0);
        idx += dir;
        if (idx > -1 && idx < children.length) {
            tid = setTimeout(fn, 100);
        }
    })();
});
```

Again, you can add any number of DIVs. See the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/6AJzP/.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best answer but hope works :

```
 wrap.click(function () {
        var time = '';

        if(c01.hasClass('c01')){
            var time = 400;
        }else{
            var time = 0;    
        }

        setTimeout(function () {
            c01.toggleClass('c01');
        }, time);

        setTimeout(function () {
            c02.toggleClass('c02');
        }, 200);

        if(c03.hasClass('c03')){
            var time = 0;
        }else{
            var time = 400;    
        }
        setTimeout(function () {
            c03.toggleClass('c03');
        }, time);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/DNzQy/2/

```
var wrap = $('#wrap'),
    c01 = $('#c01'),
    c02 = $('#c02'),
    c03 = $('#c03');

var toggle = 1;

wrap.click(function () {
    if (toggle == 1) {
        toggleC01 = 400;
        toggleC02 = 200;
        toggleC03 = 0;
        toggle = 0;
    } else {
        toggleC01 = 0;
        toggleC02 = 200;
        toggleC03 = 400;
        toggle = 1;
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        c01.toggleClass('c01');
    }, toggleC01);
    setTimeout(function () {
        c02.toggleClass('c02');
    }, toggleC02);
    setTimeout(function () {
        c03.toggleClass('c03');
    }, toggleC03);

});
```

Comment: I don't think this make c03 hide first.

Comment: nope check the fiddle link.. c03 is the one in green in the last

Comment: I see that. But second click on the yellow box, c3 doesn't hide first.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can add any number of children :

```
var children = $('#wrap div'),
    dir = 1;
$('#wrap').one('click', function click() {
    var idx;
    switch (dir) {
        case 1: idx = 0; break;
        case -1: idx = children.length - 1; break;
    }
    setTimeout(function fn() {
        children.eq(idx).toggle();
        idx += dir;
        if (idx > -1 && idx < children.length) {
            setTimeout(fn, idx * 200);
        } else {
            dir = -dir;
            $('#wrap').one('click', click);
        }
    }, idx * 200);
});
```

See the demo : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/YrUWs/.

Answer (score -2):

This could be pretty easily achieved with global variables.  When var showClass = True show them and when it is false do the other way.  In the function flip the variable after showing or hiding.

Comment: Your answer ought to demonstrate this.